# Getting value of label based on composite data

Tags: xpages

I have a custom control that has a property I have defined.  I use the composite data a label which is on the custom control.  The label displays just fine but I wanted to use the value of the label on a control that is outside the control with the label and composite data.

But it is returning null for the value of the label.   It seems like that composite data is being calculated every time the label value is accessed and the reference point for the calculation seems to be the control accessing the label value rather than the control where it is contained.

I plan to use scope variables instead but is there any way I can make composite data work?

Comment: You question is not clear Bruce, can you please provide a sample of the code you are working with so that we can understand your question a bit better please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composite data only exists inside the custom control that defines it. As such, it is far easier to reach outward than to reach inward.

In addition to scope variables, an alternative is to define a dataContext. This is technically still a use of scope variables, as it pushes a variable temporarily into the requestScope, but is slightly easier to work with because you don't have to explicitly tell it to do so... it just does it. For example:

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext
            var="labelValue"
            value="#{someExpression}" />
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:text
        value="#{labelValue}" />
    <xc:labelContainer
        labelValue="#{labelValue}" />
</xp:view>
```

In the above example, everywhere within the container to which I've attached this labelValue dataContext, I can just refer to #{labelValue}, and it will return whatever value the expression for that dataContext returned. This provides you, then, a single variable that can be used within the XPage itself, but also passed into custom controls.

Comment: I guess my question is why it would be done that way?  You would think the CC would compute the value for you and store the result in the label.   They as far as any other control is concerned it would be like reading a static value.

Comment: Component properties can either have a local value or a value binding. Calling setValue() on the component directly gives it a static local value. If, instead, you're defining its value in the CC as referencing the compositeData, then you've defined a value binding. This causes the expression to be recalculated any time the value property is requested. So you could call getValue() on the label from outside the CC, which refers to compositeData, which is being passed something from outside. Better to just consolidate the evaluation, both for runtime performance and for code clarity.

Comment: Thanks.   How would you consolidate the evaluation?   Seems it would make sense that (at least in this instance) that I would only want to evaluate when the page is loaded.   Is there anyway to do that here?    Maybe do it on Page Load and set the value of the label there with the composite data?

Comment: Using a dataContext, as described in my answer, consolidates the evaluation: only the dataContext evaluates the expression, then the same result can be referenced from multiple places using just the variable of the dataContext. To ensure it is only calculated once, set its value binding to compute on page load (${someExpression} instead of #{someExpression}... the dollar sign means evaluate it once, then don't recalculate again).

Comment: Thanks Tim,   I tried the dataContext and it works great.   My only other question is, I set the static value of the label to  "#{labelLocation}"  but when I saved the CC, it changed it to labelLocation. (period) .  Is this normal?    And if I changed it to On Page Load, the expression went away.  So that I did was change it back to Javascript, made it computed, made it On Page load and entered a value of "#{labelLocation}".   Is this what I should have done?

Answer (score 1):

I like Tim's suggestion with the data context. However if you have to, you could access the value on the propertyMap of the control. This wouldn't be the label but the composite data. This is how components could 'talk back'

Comment: stwissel,  How would I access the Property Map of the control?

Comment: var theControl = getComponent("theControlID");
var pMap = theControl.getPropertyMap();
// Ulrich has an example: http://www.eknori.de/2011-07-15/get-custom-properties-from-another-custom-control/
Need to check for null!